# Round floating point to hundreths' place

Tags: php, floating-point, rounding

I'm doing some calculations in PHP and I'm getting numbers that look like 0.20758605003357.

How can I round that so the output is 0.21 in that case. Or more generally, so that the number, whatever it is, is rounded to the hundredths' place.

Comment: `echo round(0.20758605003357, 2);` [o.O](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use PHP's `round`function:

```
echo round($number, 2);
```

see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: how is this different than number_format() ? Or does number_format() only shave off at the given place and not round.

Comment: number_format will round the output, one of the "features" number_format provides it's that you may add coma's after each 1000. Check out [the examples in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 2):

```
number_format($number,2);
```

the second parameter is how many digits after the decimal.

Also, there is money_format (if you want it rounded). in USD:

```
money_format('%i',$number);
```

Comment: I need something that rounds, but I didn't know those functions existed. I will learn them and use them later if needed. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, `round()` is probably your best bet. - i din't realize it had a precision parameter.